# Update item inside the cache and then call again findAll items doesn't update the item

Tags: java, spring, list, caching, spring-cache

I have created two `services` which uses `Spring Cache`. In the first method I am putting all records which are made while app is starting:

```
   @CachePut(value = "items")
    public Item save(Item item){
        System.out.println("----------------- z cachea udated" + item);
        return itemRepository.saveAndFlush(item);
    }
```

So when app is running in first steps I populate my `cache`. Then I am getting all records:

```
 @Cacheable(value = "items")
    public Page<Item> getItems(Pageable pageRequest){
        System.out.println("----------------- z cachea PAGEABLE");

        Page<Item> all = itemRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
        System.out.println("----------------- all" + all.getContent());
        return all;
    }
```

Then I update only one record using `save()` method and again getting all records. And in that moment my `cache` hasn't been changed at all. Inside the `cache` there all records which were in the first call of method. How to change inside the `cache` only that record which has been affected by the update?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `@Cacheable(value = "items")` to `@Cacheable(value="items", key="all")`

Comment: This is a vary poor solution because it causes errors. I have tried it..